# NLog user-specific logfile

Tags: nlog

How could I use NLog to create a user-specific logfile the file name equivalent to the username? I understand that you can use variables in layouts, but the file name attribute is set at the level of the target. I would like to be able to do something like `filename="C:\pathtologfiles\${myApp:user}.txt"` and in the calling class, `ClassLogger.Debug("user did something", thisUser.Username)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it (in VB, unfortunately.) You would of course need to implement your own `_UsernameIsMeaningfulInThisContext` and `_GetUsername`.

**In nlog config**

```
<variable name="AppLogDir" value="C:\inetpub\ApplicationLogging\MyApplication" />
...
<targets>
  ...
  <target name="UserSpecificLogfile"
          xsi:type="File"
          fileName="${AppLogDir}\Users\AppUser_${event-context:item=AppUsername}.txt"
          createDirs="true" />
</targets>
<rules>
  ...
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" maxLevel="Fatal" writeTo="UserSpecificLogfile" />
</rules>
```

**In calling class**

```
Private Property _ClassLogger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
...
Private Sub _LogMaybeUser(ByVal nLogLevel As NLog.LogLevel, ByVal nMsg As String)
{
     Dim logfileUser As String = "Unknown"
     If _UsernameIsMeaningfulInThisContext() { logfileUser = _GetUsername() }
     Dim logInfo As New LogEventInfo(nLogLevel, "", nMsg)
     logInfo.Properties("AppUsername") = logfileUser
     ClassLogger.Log(logInfo)
}
```